# Node Js Acessing a Jason File

Tags: node.js, json, discord.js, file-access

still new to JSON and while ive searched the net and created a function to create a init file if none exists i'm coming up blank for search and retrive the data of the new existing file or how I add new entries or update new entries

so far i can do a read file and export the resits in a console log so i know the assignment work, its a global variable so the data should persist out of the read file loop but when i try and access it later to make the local array i'll pull data from and use for updating later it reads as undefined.

```
fs.readFile(path, 'utf8', (error, data) => {
    if(error){
      console.log(error);
      return;
    }
    //console.log(JSON.parse(data));
    JSONData = JSON.parse(data);
    for (let i = 0; i < JSONData.length; i++) {
      console.log(i+": ["+JSONData[i].unique+"] "+JSONData[i].name);
    }
});//fs.readFile
  var playerKey = "KuroTO";
    playerKey = playerKey.toLowerCase();
    
    for (let i = 0; i < JSONData.length; i++) {
      if (JSONData[i].unique.toLowerCase() == playerKey){
        console.log("["+i+"] "+JSONData[i].unique.toLowerCase()+": "+playerKey);
        PlayerCard1.push(JSONData[i].userid);//0
        PlayerCard1.push(JSONData[i].username);//1
        PlayerCard1.push(JSONData[i].unique);//2
        PlayerCard1.push(JSONData[i].name);//3
        PlayerCard1.push(JSONData[i].avatarurl);//4
        PlayerCard1.push(JSONData[i].level);//5
        PlayerCard1.push(JSONData[i].Rank);//6
        PlayerCard1.push(JSONData[i].henshined);//7
        PlayerCard1.push(JSONData[i].Strength);//8
        PlayerCard1.push(JSONData[i].Perception);//9
        PlayerCard1.push(JSONData[i].Endurance);//10
        PlayerCard1.push(JSONData[i].Wisdom);//11
        PlayerCard1.push(JSONData[i].Intelligence)//12;
        PlayerCard1.push(JSONData[i].Luck)//13;
        PlayerCard1.push(JSONData[i].Agility)//14;
        PlayerCard1.push(JSONData[i].Flexability)//15;
        PlayerCard1.push(JSONData[i].RatedSpeed)//16;
      };//if unique matches
    };//for
```

this is ther psudo code concept im trying to do
if (JSONData.stringify.unique == {SearchUID}){toonname = JSONData.stringify.name;}

as i understand it you cant really apend just rewrite the file over again with new data and i think i can figure that out on my own once i cand figure out how to real the file into an array i can search like above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read JSON, simply require the file.

JSON:

```json
{
    "key": "H"
}
```

JS:

```js
let jsonFile = require("./path/to/json");
console.log(jsonFile.key); // H
```

Editing is just as simple.

```js
let jsonFile = require("./path/to/json");
jsonFile.key = "A" 
console.log(jsonFile.key) // A
```

Saving edits requires use of FileSystem:

```js
const fs = require("fs")
let jsonFile = require("./path/to/json");
jsonFile.key = "A" 
// first argument is the file path
// second argument is the JSON to write - the file is overwritten already 
// due to above, so just JSON.stringify() the required file.
// third argument is an error callback
fs.writeFile("./path/to/jsonFile", JSON.stringify(jsonFile), (err) => {
    if (err) throw new Error(err);
});
```

This can also be used to slightly clean up your current init function if you wanted, but that's up to you of course.

Comment: does the editing still work if my file is basically several associative array ie


[{"name":"Lexx Allolia", "Rank":"Rider"},{"name":"Dan Kuroto {Bugster}", "Rank":"Rider"},{"name":"Panda Blecker","Rank":"6th Ranger"}]

Comment: Yes, but you'd have to iterate the array and use `jsonFile[0][index]["name"] = value` (0 should be the array's index in the JSON, so 0 or whatever else the key/index is, i.e. `[{name: "name1"}, {"name": "name2"}]` would be edited like `jsonFile[0]["name"] = "name1_new"` or something, if I understand you properly

Comment: yeah figured as much, so JSONFile is just a normal associative array, and i process it like such, then i use stringify to to it into well a string, and essentially over write the source file?
will the output be propery new line formated, cause when i read the default if none file creatd from my init function its all one line instead of looking pretty

Comment: `JSON.stringify()` makes it one long line, as shown here: https://i.imgur.com/hiq1GAb.png if you want to read it properly, try to use `JSON.parse()` and `console.log()` it